# react native native base ListItem touchableHighlightStyle

Tags: react-native, native-base

Any idea on how to change the touch style for a ListItem?
"Suggestions / Contact" highlights with that left grey on touch.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Switch } from 'react-native';
import Constants from '../models/Constants';
import Styles from '../styles/Styles';
import { Container, Content, Header, List, ListItem, Body, CheckBox, Title, Left, Right, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';

import { Col, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import Colours from '../models/Colours';
import SettingsData from '../data/SettingsData';


export default class Settings extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

render() {
    const isKM = true;

    return (

            <Container style={Styles.dark}>
                <Header transparent noShadow>
                    <Left style={Styles.headerSide}/>
                    <Body style={Styles.headerBody}>
                        <Title style={Styles.headerTitle}>Settings</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right style={Styles.headerSide}/>
                </Header>
                <ScrollView>

                    <Content>
                        <List>

                            <ListItem style={Styles.listItem} titleStyle={Styles.title} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={Styles.listTitle}>Sign up</Text>
                                        <Text note style={Styles.subtitle}>To save your data when swapping device</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                                <Right>
                                    <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>

                            <ListItem  style={Styles.listItem} titleStyle={Styles.title}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={Styles.listTitle}>Smart Track</Text>
                                        <Text note style={Styles.subtitle}>Will not compute stationary time</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                                <Right>
                                    <Switch value={this.state.smartTrack} onValueChange={this.onSmartTrack} />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>



                            <ListItem style={Styles.listItem} titleStyle={Styles.title} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About')}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={Styles.listTitle}>Store</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                                <Right>
                                    <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>

                            <ListItem style={Styles.listItem} titleStyle={Styles.title} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('About')}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={Styles.listTitle}>About</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                                <Right>
                                    <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>

                            <ListItem style={Styles.listItem} titleStyle={Styles.title} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Suggest')}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={Styles.listTitle}>Suggestions / Contact</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                                <Right>
                                    <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>

                            <ListItem style={Styles.listItem} titleStyle={Styles.title} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Reset')}>
                                <Left>
                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={Styles.listTitle}>Reset all data</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                                <Right>
                                    <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                                </Right>
                            </ListItem>


                        </List>
                    </Content>
                </ScrollView>
            </Container>

    );
    }
}
```

Style:

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Colours from '../models/Colours';

const MARGIN = 20;
const h = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const w = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const pageH = h - 65 - 50 - 5; // header, tabs, safe

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
dark: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.DARK
},
black: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.BLACk
},
page: {
    //flex: 1,
    //flexDirection: 'row'.
    backgroundColor: Colours.DARK
},
centerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
},
fullPage: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: pageH
},
modalBG: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    flex: 1,
    width: w,
    height: h,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: Colours.RGBA_BLACK
},
centerBlackMargin: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    margin: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colours.RGBA_BLACK
},

list: {
    borderColor: Colours.DARK
},
listTitle: {
    color: Colours.WHITE,
    fontSize: 16
},

listItem: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.DARK,
    borderColor: Colours.DARKER,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    height: 60
    //borderBottomColor: '#bbb',
    //borderTopWidth: 0,
    //borderBottomWidth: 0
    //StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
},
listItemPress: {
    borderColor: Colours.DARKER
},

input: {
    color: Colours.GREY
    //height: 60
    //borderBottomColor: '#bbb',
    //borderTopWidth: 0,
    //borderBottomWidth: 0
    //StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
},
textarea: {
    color: Colours.GREY,
    fontSize: 18,
    marginLeft: 14,
    marginTop: 15,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: Colours.DARKER
},
listItemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.DARK
},

listCols: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: 10
},

subtitle: {
    color: Colours.DARKGREY,
    backgroundColor: Colours.DARK,
    fontSize: 12
},

title: {
    color: Colours.WHITE,
    fontSize: 18
},

headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: Colours.WHITE
},

headerSide:{
    flex: 0,
    flexBasis: 48
},
headerBody:{
    flex: 1,
},

bigTitle: {
    fontSize: 48,
    color: Colours.WHITE
},
midTitle: {
    fontSize: 36,
    color: Colours.WHITE
},
smallTitle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: Colours.DARKGREY
},


checkbox: {
    marginRight: MARGIN
},
// input: {
//  width: 200,
//  height: 40,
//  fontSize: 24,
//  backgroundColor: Colours.RED
// },

sendButton: {
    marginTop: 25,
    paddingRight: 15,
    paddingLeft: 15,
},
sidePadding: {
    paddingRight: MARGIN,
    paddingLeft: MARGIN,
},
trackFooter: {
    paddingTop: MARGIN,
    paddingRight: MARGIN,
    paddingLeft: MARGIN,
},

button: {
    color: Colours.WHITE,
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: Colours.RED
},

cancelTrack: {
    color: Colours.GREY,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10
},
textWarn: {
    color: Colours.RED,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 5
},
textCenter: {
    color: Colours.GREY,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    //fontSize: 21
},

icon: {
    color: Colours.GREY
},

bgRed: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.RED
},
bgBlue: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.BLUE
},
bgYellow: {
    backgroundColor: Colours.YELLOW
},

dashNotEnough: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 21,
    color: Colours.DARKGREY
},

dashFooter: {
    height:150,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    //backgroundColor: Colours.YELLOW
},

centeredScreen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    //backgroundColor: Colours.YELLOW
},
centeredScreenCol: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    //backgroundColor: Colours.BLUE
}


});

export default Styles;
```

Comment: Can you add the code to the generate the issue?

Comment: sorry about that, forgot it. added component and styles. (this happened after ejected the theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some variables in the theme, that you need to change in order to remove the *left white bar*.

The **Native Base** *ListItem* theme consist of [`listBtnUnderlayColor: '#DDD'`](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/c737188cb224e76bc6b8a89e9cb4f6d874a84db3/src/theme/variables/platform.js#L200) which gives the color for the touchable interaction for the underlay items under the **List**

Therefore you need to replace `marginLeft` to `paddingLeft` in the ListItem ejected component [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/c737188cb224e76bc6b8a89e9cb4f6d874a84db3/src/theme/components/ListItem.js#L433) as

```
paddingLeft: variables.listItemPadding + 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [ListItem Selected](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#listitem-selected-headref) and [ListItem NoIndent](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#listitem-noIndent-headref) and List component [theme variables](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/ThemeVariables.html) from docs